# How to write a tf publisher for laser scanning

Tags: ros, laser, tf-broadcaster, learning-tf, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I got a question regarding the tf publisher. I try to visualize my Hokuyo laserdata in Rviz. I dont have a robot yet or something, the Hokuyo is just standing on the desk :)
So I wrote a little publisher for the Hokuyo to publish the laser data and now I want to visualize them in rviz. But for now Rviz is complaining about Global Status: Fixed Frame "Fixed frame...does not exist" and so on. So my approach is to write a publisher so I can just select my frame from the laserscanner from the dropdown menu in Rviz. But for now I cant just write a publisher using this tutorial [TF Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29). I maybe just don't get or understand it :) But I hope someone of you can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203689/how-to-write-a-tf-publisher-for-laser-scanning/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just an answer by myself. There is no need to write a tf publisher just to view the laser data in rviz. Just start (in this case) the urg_node with `rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"` and start rviz with `rosrun rviz rviz` after this select in rviz as global frame `/laser` (or just type it in) than add a new display with laserscan and the topic /laser. here you go and watch your data.

---

Originally posted by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) with karma: 232 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1